# Callback function not being executed on dojo.xhrGet in IE

Tags: ajax, dojo, callback, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to use dojo.xhrGet to get some json back from a php file.  Everything works great in Firefox, but IE doesn't work at all and Chrome can be hit or miss.  The problem is the callback isn't being executed (in the load argument).  I checked the Inspector in Chrome and the request is getting returned with the correct data, readyState of 4 and status of 200, but the callback isn't executing.  Any ideas what could be going wrong?  Could this happen because of a scoping issue?

```
var xhrArgs = {
    url : "/phpHelpers/getImages.php",
    handleAs : "json",
    load : function(result) {
        alert('load callback');
    },
    error : function(error) {
        alert('error');
    }
};

this.def = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
```

Comment: Are you sure that "console.log(result)" method not cause an error in IE (you can simply replace "console.log(result)" to "alert('Data loaded')" to check it)?

Comment: @Andrei - This was a mistake when writing up the question, I had a alerts in my code.  I have edited to correct it.

Comment: This is strange. See if you can reproduce a minimal example at JSFiddle.

Comment: @missingo - I tried to replicate it in JSFiddle but wasn't able to.  I found out what was causing my issue, check answer below.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to track down the problem... Was all because of this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
```

I had that included in my main file, for some reason it was hindering the callbacks from firing in both ie and chrome (although Chrome was hit or miss).  I not sure why firebug would cause this, but removing the include fixed the issue.  Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `preventCache` [parameter](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/xhrGet.html)?  IE in particular likes to cache xhr GETs, unless you have the 'always refresh from server' option ticked in the developer tools.

```
var xhrArgs = {
  url : "/phpHelpers/getImages.php",
  handleAs : "json",
  preventCache: true,
  load : function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  },
  error : function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```